_C.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2at10TensorBase8data_ptrIdEEPT_v
Trying to use detectron2 on an application im working. What is the reason for this error and how can I fix it?
I have seen similar questions mentioning that the problem may be that the torch and detectron2 are different versions. I also tried pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html for that but still didnt work.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PieChart.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "/mnt/c/Users/admin/Desktop/SEM/SEM/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from detectron2.structures import Boxes, pairwise_iou
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/sem5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/structures/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .image_list import ImageList
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/sem5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/structures/image_list.py", line 8, in <module>
    from detectron2.layers.wrappers import shapes_to_tensor
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/sem5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/layers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .deform_conv import DeformConv, ModulatedDeformConv
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/sem5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/layers/deform_conv.py", line 11, in <module>
    from detectron2 import _C
ImportError: /root/anaconda3/envs/sem5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/_C.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2at10TensorBase8data_ptrIdEEPT_v


Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117097/c-cpython-38-x86-64-linux-gnu-so-undefined-symbol-zn6caffe28typemeta21-typem
